# Strange elisp byte-compiler warning about unused variables

Tags: byte-compilation, warning

The following elisp code inserts `hello world!` 10 times:

```
-*- lexical-binding: t -*-
(dotimes (i 10) (insert "hello world!\n"))
```

If I byte-compile that code, I get the following message:

```
hellos.el:2:1:Warning: Unused lexical variable `i'
```

This is strange ... `i` is used to count from 0 to 9, even if it is not used in the repeated code. How am I supposed to loop 10 times ?!

Even stranger, the warning message disappears if I set

```
-*- lexical-binding: nil -*-
```

Go figure ...

Is this a bug (admittedly minor) in the emacs compiler? Is there a way to loop 10 times without using a counting variable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't use `i` and that's what the byte-compiler tells you.
To let the byte-compiler know that you're aware of the fact that the variable is unused, give it a name that starts with an underscore.  E.g.

```
(dotimes (_ 10) ...)
```

or

```
(dotimes (_i 10) ...)
```

Comment: Thanks !! BTW, why is the byte-compiler not complaining when `lexical-binding` is not set?

Comment: Because with dynamic scoping the byte compiler can't be sure that the variable is *really* not used (e.g. the `insert` function in your example could theoretically make use of it).